# Iterating a Multidimensional Array in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, multidimensional-array, iteration

I am having trouble iterating through a multidimensional array in TypeScript. In order to store the data into a db, I need to convert the multidimensional array into a one dimensional one.

My function:

```
storeDevices() {
    let tempDeviceList: Device[][] = this.dataStorageService.getDevices();
    console.log(tempDeviceList);
    console.log(tempDeviceList[1]);
    console.log(tempDeviceList[1][1]);
    console.log(tempDeviceList.length);
  }
```

```
console.log(tempDeviceList);
```

results in https://pastebin.com/mb2B9yrM
I am using this as a lookup table which is why the first element is often null.

I do not understand why

```
    console.log(tempDeviceList[1]); //undefined
    console.log(tempDeviceList[1][1]); //undefined
    console.log(tempDeviceList.length); //0
```

result in undefined and 0. Because of this I am not able to iterate over the array. Based on the printed JSON, those elements should exist.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Merge/flatten an array of arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10865025/merge-flatten-an-array-of-arrays)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const data = [
  null,
  [
    null,
    {
      "deviceID": 1,
      "deviceType": 1,
      "updateFrequency": 1,
      "lastUpdate": 1557679860000,
      "payload": [
        22,
        31,
        32
        .... rest of your array data
```

Then you can create a Util class:

```
class Utils {
  public flatten(arr: any[]): any[] {
    // in node 11+, FF and Crome: 
    // return arr.flat();
    return [].concat(...arr);
  }

  // Use if you want to exclude null, undefined
  // or any falsey value from final array
  public compact(arr: any[]): any[] {
    return arr.filter(Boolean);
  }
}

const utils = new Utils();
const tempDeviceList = utils.compact(utils.flatten(data));


console.log(tempDeviceList[1]); // {deviceID: 2....
console.log(tempDeviceList.length); // 16
```

[Read more about the new Array.prototype.flat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat)

Comment: Alright now I am totally confused: When I manually define the data = [] like you did it works. When I use `let tempDeviceList: Device[][] = this.dataStorageService.getDevices();`, which printed is exactly the same as data, it does not work. Where is the difference?

Comment: Maybe the return of your data call is Async and you need to await for it? What's in getDevices function?

Answer (score 0):

Converting a multi-dimensional array into a single dimensional one is also known as *array flattening*. There's plenty of resources on this topic, [here's one on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10865025/merge-flatten-an-array-of-arrays) to get you started.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried various methods and they all return an empty array. I guess this is still related to my original problem described above.